# rowCount in mysql dealing with certain columns with values

Tags: php, mysql, count, pdo, row

Can someone help me rowCount() when I have values and empty values in mysql

for example:

```
id        column1          column2           idcolumn
1           2                                   1  
2           3                                   1
3           1                                   1
4           0                                   1


$CountQuery = "SELECT column1 FROM follow WHERE idcolumn= ?";
$Count = $dbh->prepare($CountQuery);
$Count -> execute(array($idcolumn)); //where $idcolumn = 1
$num_1 = $Count->rowCount();
echo $num_1;
```

this should give me a count of 4, but I'm trying to distinguish between column1 and column2, so I can find counts where if I wanted to create a query with $num_2, it should give me a count of 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT(column)` to count the number of rows with non-NULL values in that column.

```
$CountQuery = "SELECT COUNT(column1) AS `count1`, COUNT(column2) AS `count2` FROM follow WHERE idcolumn = ?";
$Count = $dbh->prepare($CountQuery);
$Count->execute(array($idcolumn)); //where $idcolumn = 1
$row = $Count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$num_1 = $row['count1'];
$num_2 = $row['count2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

From manual, [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) doesn't work for `SELECT` queries.

> ROW_COUNT() returns the number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted
>   by the last statement if it was an UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT. For
>   other statements, the value may not be meaningful.

Alternatively you can use:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS column1 FROM follow WHERE idcolumn= ?

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

you can use this query to get count of non-null values:

```
SELECT column(column) FROM follow WHERE idcolumn= ?;
```

or you can use this query to get count of all rows:

```
SELECT column(1) FROM follow WHERE idcolumn= ?;
```